# Show that $\int_0^de^{-tx}g(x)dx\sim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{g(0)}{t}$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $d>0$. Let $g\in C^0([0,d])$  such that $g(0)\ne0$.

Show that $$\int_0^de^{-tx}g(x)dx\sim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{g(0)}{t}$$

How can I prove that ?

It's the first time I see this kind of exercise

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: @JLBarba The limit is $t$ not $d$. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start. Making the change of variables $y=tx$ yields

> $$ \int_0^de^{-tx}g(x)dx = \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{td} g\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)e^{-y} dy. $$

I think you can advance now.

**Note:**

> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y}dy = 1. $$

Comment: @Cryme: Good job. You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this limit is zero.

**Proof.**
Let's use the definition of limit:
$\forall\epsilon , \exists\delta \ |\int_0^de^{-tx}g(x)dx|<\delta$

As $g\in C^0([0,d])$, $|g|<c$, is bounded

In addition, it's known that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{-tx}=0$. Therefore for above $\epsilon ,\exists\delta_1 $ such $ |e^{-tx}|<\delta_1$ 

Putting all together:
$$\left|\int_0^de^{-tx}g(x)dx\right|< c \left|\int_0^de^{-tx}dx\right| < c \ d \ \delta_1 = \delta$$

This should be all.